# creating grid with 2 columns and auto number of rows based on number of list items

Tags: css, css-grid

This CSS Grid stuff is hard!  I am trying to create a basic 2 column grid layout from my list of items.  It should auto decide the number of rows based on the number of list items.  I have it working and looking nicely except it fills in the row first then goes down to the next row.  I want it to fill in the entire column first then go to the next column.  So I thought I could just add `grid-auto-flow: column;` to my `ul`.  But for some reason that turns it into just one row.

Here is the CSS I currently have:

```
ul.dept-list{display:grid;grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(200px,1fr));}
```

<s>I have tried just using css3 columns.  Here is what it looks like with adding `columns: 2;  -webkit-columns: 2;  -moz-columns: 2;` to the `ul`.</s>

[image]

And here is what it looks like with my grid code:
[image]

**UPDATE: Turns out I had those list items floated left from some other css.  I got it to work with CSS columns after all.  Still wish someone could tell me how to do it with grid.**

**Here is my final CSS code I used to get it looking good**

```
ul.dept-list{columns:2;-webkit-columns:2;-moz-columns:2;height:auto;}

ul.dept-list li{display:block;width:250px;float:none;}

ul.dept-list li a.dropdown-item{padding:.25rem .5rem;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that.  It looks horrible compared to the grid option.

Comment: Nevermind, they were floated left causing the horrible formatting.  Gave them a width and removed the floats and its working nicely!